# animate toggle and background

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I try to:
- Click to animate the div logo
- Click again the div logo and it should go to the initial position
- Click to the background and it should go to the initial position (if it is not already)

I set a var to check what is the position of the div, but it does not work and I do not know if it is the right direction.

Here is to play: http://jsfiddle.net/xNMZ3/

HTML:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="background"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body{margin:0;}

#logo {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-40px;left: 5%;
    width:70px; height:80px;
    background:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:1;
}

#background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background:yellow;
    z-index:0;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    var hidden = $("#logo").css("bottom","-40" + "px");
    $("#logo").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

      if (hidden) {
        $("#logo").animate({bottom: "0"}, 500);
      } else {
        $("#logo").stop.animate({bottom: "-40"}, 500);
      }

    });

    $("#background").click(function() {
      if (!hidden) {
        $("#logo").animate({bottom: "-40"}, 500);
      }     
    });
})
```

Comment: You're setting `hidden` on pageload, so it will always contain something and be truthy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var hidden = true;
    var $logo = $("#logo");
    $logo.click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var bottom = hidden ? "0" : "-40";
        $(this).stop().animate({
            bottom: bottom
        }, 500);
        hidden = !hidden;
    });

    $("#background").click(function () {
        if (!hidden) {
            $logo.animate({
                bottom: "-40"
            }, 500, function () {
                hidden = !hidden;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xNMZ3/2/)

Comment: If you click logo, then background and then again logo, you should click twice to make it animate

Comment: I works but I do not understand hidden = !hidden; can you explain this please?

Comment: Give me some time. I am middle of something. I will update my answer with comments after some time.

Comment: @Nrc: See `hidden = !hidden` is simply a one-line code for this `if (hidden == true) {
    hidden = false;
} else {
    hidden = true;
}`